# Pip installation in virtualenv broken

Tags: python

I get this error from the virtualenv's pip installation:

```
➜  myproject git:(master) ✗ pyenv/bin/pip --help
Failed checking if argv[0] is an import path entry
ValueError: character U+6e657970 is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff]
Fatal Python error: no mem for sys.argv
ValueError: character U+6e657970 is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff]

Current thread 0x00007fff767c5000 (most recent call first):
[1]    10941 abort      pyenv/bin/pip --help
```

The virtual env's python works, the system python and pip work (all python3).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out that **virtualenv hard links the python executable to the system python**, so that when I upgraded python, it got out of line with the virtual env's pip installation.

Posting here for other to find, in case this happens to them.

Solution is to wipe the `pyenv` folder, and reinstall a fresh virtualenv (if you've been using a `requirements.txt` file, this is what the virtual env is designed to do!

Comment: Hi. Could you do more specific? What is the pyenv folder? I just recreate a new virtualenv, but I still have this issue.

Comment: `pyenv` is the folder I built the virtualenv with.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/), you can install pip in a virtual environment by typing the following command when your virtual environment is activated:

```
python -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

For your information, ensurepip is an in-built Python module that serves the purpose of installing pip in your Python environment.

This solution can be used if you do not want to start a fresh new virtual environment and you want to retain your dependencies

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you. Should be the accepted answer to "fix" a broken pip installation, not to destroy your venv and start over.

Answer (score -2):

First, try updating pip

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

if this does not fix it, I would try uninstalling pip and then reinstall.

to remove try:

```
sudo pip uninstall pip
```

then install again.

```
pip install -U pip setuptools
```

also i am assuming your are using linux or mac. on windows commands differ.

Comment: Yeah, but see the problem? The pip script didn't run at all (if it won't run the --help flag, it won't run the upgrade...).

Comment: Doesn't look like you read the question.  The `pip` command is broken so these commands won't work at all.